# Python 3 need assistance

Tags: python-3.x

```
def bubble_down(L, start, end):
    """ (list, int, int) -> NoneType

    Bubble down through L from indexes end through start, swapping items that are out of place.

    >>> L = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    >>> bubble_down(L, 1, 3)
    >>> L
    [4, 1, 3, 2, 0]
    """
    for i in range(start, end):
        if L[i] < L[i]:
            L[i - 1], L[i] = L[i], L [i - 1]
```

This function won't do.... and I don't get why docstring example L return [4, 1, 3, 2, 0], not [4, 1, 2, 3, 0]

Comment: Write the code to a file (do not use interactive mode for non-trivial one-liners). Your `if` condition is wrong. There must be `i - 1` as one of the indices. This way, it never holds (always `False`) and nothing happens in the loop.

Comment: A comment for downvoters. Please, notice the asker's points and the nation. So, he probably is a beginner, and may have difficulties to express the question. The downvote button is not for "I do not like it" or "I do not understand it". Write your comment if you downvote.

Comment: (assuming you fix the `[i-1]`) You are only going over the list once so not all required changes will necessarily happen on the first pass, it is a bubble sort so you need to keep checking until you know it is all correctly sorted.

Comment: I did try to fix it by putting L[i] > L[i-1] but it still causes problem because its returning [4, 3, 2, 1, 0] instead of [4, 1, 3, 2, 0]. I assume its 1, 3, 2 instead of 3, 2, 1 because of unsorted/sorted issue, but how can I express that in a function?

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Your comparison is wrong (you are comparing the same element), and you probably want to think a bit more about your end bondary.
Most importantly, you want to iterate the process until there is no change.

Here's a correct version:

```
def  bubble_down(to_sort, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end  = len(to_sort)
    did_change = True
    while did_change:
        did_change = False
        for i in range(start, end-1):
            if to_sort[i] > to_sort[i+1]:
                did_change = True
                to_sort[i], to_sort[i+1] = to_sort[i+1], to_sort[i]

    return to_sort


>>> print(bubble_down([5, 7, 6 , 1]))
[1, 5, 6, 7]
>>> print bubble_down([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the step and swap the end and start since we are iterating backwards from end to start. The comparison needs to be between L[i] and L[i - 1] as well.

```
def bubble_down(L, start, end):        
    for i in range(end, start, -1):
            if L[i] < L[i - 1]:
                L[i], L[i - 1] = L[i - 1], L[i]
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to include the step in your solution

```
def bubble_down(L, start, end):
    """ (list, int, int) -> NoneType

    Bubble down through L from indexes end through start, swapping items that are out of place.

    >>> L = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    >>> bubble_down(L, 1, 3)
    >>> L
    [4, 1, 3, 2, 0]
    """
    for i in range(start, end, -1):
        if L[i] < L[i]:
            L[i - 1], L[i] = L[i], L [i - 1]
```